# Value returned from SQL Server stored procedure not converting properly

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a row returned from SQL Server and an integer column value that is not converting properly to boolean in C#.

I want to convert an integer 1 to boolean true. But it does not do that. It converts the 1 to false or thinks it is 0 and converts to false.

```
blogPublishedByBlogId.LikeDisabled = Convert.ToBoolean(getblogPublishedByBlogIdReader["LikeDisabled"]);
```

Here is the row returned from the stored procedure via SSMS:

[image]

The `LikeDisabled` column is a an integer and has a value = 1, however it gets converted to a value of 0 in C#. Why? A simple thing like this should work. It does not make sense.

Here is the code that shows it after the stored procedure is called and taking the data and putting it into a model.

I put in 2 lines of 'test code' to see the integer value. It is returned by the stored procedure as a integer value = 1, yet after the convert function- Convert.ToInt32, I get a 0. See below.

[image]

Here is the fully populated model a few lines down. The booleans are both false when the `LikeDisabled` one should be = true.

[image]

Here is the stored procedure. It gets the data needed from the database table and also sets the `LikeDisabled` and `DisLikeDisabled` based upon `@LikeOrDislikeIndicator = 'L'` which is currently and an 'L'.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetBlogPublishedByBlogId]
    @a_UserName   varchar(250) = NULL,
    @a_IpAddress  varchar(250) = NULL,
    @a_BlogId     int = NULL,
    @a_UserId     int = NULL
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RowCount                  int,
            @ReturnCode                int,
            @CurrentDateTime           datetime,  
            @Count                     int,
            @UserType                  varchar(25) = '',
            @LikeOrDislikeIndicator    char(1) = '',   -- 'L' for like, 'D' for dislike.
            @BlogId                    int = 0,   
            @BlogTitle                 varchar(250) = '',
            @BlogContent               varchar(max) = '',
            @LikeCount                 int = 0,  
            @DisLikeCount              int = 0,  
            @ModifiedDateTime          datetime = NULL,
            @CreatedDateTime           datetime = NULL,
            @LikeDisabled              int = 0, 
            @DisLikeDisabled           int = 0,
            @Message                   varchar(max),
            @ApiMessageOut             varchar(max),
            @ApiAccessSwitchOut        bit

SELECT @CurrentDateTime = GETDATE()


DECLARE @ErrorLine      AS INT;
DECLARE @ErrorMessage       AS VARCHAR(2048);
DECLARE @ErrorNumber        AS INT; 
DECLARE @ErrorSeverity      AS INT; 
DECLARE @ErrorState     AS INT; 
DECLARE @DatabaseName       AS VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE @ServerName     AS VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE @ErrorDescription   AS VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @CRLF           AS VARCHAR(2);
    
BEGIN TRY

   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   IF ( ( @a_UserName  = '' OR @a_UserName  IS NULL ) OR ( @a_IpAddress = '' OR @a_IpAddress IS NULL ) 
   OR ( @a_BlogId IS NULL ) OR ( @a_UserId IS NULL ) )
      BEGIN
         SELECT @Message = 'Warning - invalid parameters. They cannot be null or empty.'    

         IF ( @a_UserName = '' OR @a_UserName IS NULL )
             BEGIN
                SET @a_UserName = 'No "user name" parameter provided.'
             END

         IF ( @a_IpAddress = '' OR @a_IpAddress IS NULL )
             BEGIN
                SET @a_IpAddress = 'No "ip address" parameter provided.'
             END

        RAISERROR (@Message, 16, 1)
      END
   ELSE
      BEGIN
           -- Do the API security check. If this user is valid, you can continue with further processing.
           SELECT @ReturnCode = -1
           EXECUTE @ReturnCode = dbo.GetApiAccess
                     @CurrentDateTime,
                     @a_UserName,
                     @a_IpAddress,
                     @a_ApiAccessSwitchFromGet = @ApiAccessSwitchOut OUTPUT,
                     @a_ApiMessageFromGet = @ApiMessageOut OUTPUT

           IF @ReturnCode = -1
                BEGIN 
                   RAISERROR ('Critical Error - procedure GetBlogPublishedByBlogId failed during execute of procedure GetApiAccess', 16, 1 )
                END
    
           -- Web api access was granted. 
           IF @ApiAccessSwitchOut = 1
               BEGIN
                   SELECT @BlogId = Blogid
                      ,@BlogTitle = BlogTitle
                      ,@BlogContent = BlogContent
                      ,@LikeCount = LikeCount
                      ,@DisLikeCount = DisLikeCount
                      ,@ModifiedDateTime = ModifiedDateTime 
                                  ,@CreatedDateTime = CreatedDateTime       
                   FROM dbo.Blog
                   WHERE ( BlogId = @a_BlogId AND ActiveSwitch = 1 )

                   SELECT @ReturnCode = @@ERROR,
                                  @RowCount = @@ROWCOUNT

                   IF @ReturnCode <> 0
                       BEGIN 
                          SELECT @Message = 'Critical Error - procedure GetBlogPublishedByBlogId during the 1st select.'
                          RAISERROR (@Message, 16, 1)
                       END  

                    IF @RowCount = 0
                        BEGIN 
                               SELECT 2 as Status
                              ,0 as Blogid
                              ,'' as BlogTitle
                              ,'' as BlogContent
                              ,0 as LikeCount
                              ,0 as DisLikeCount
                              ,NULL as ModifiedDateTime 
                                              ,NULL as CreatedDateTime
                              ,@LikeDisabled as LikeDisabled
                                      ,@DisLikeDisabled as DisLikeDisabled
                        END 
                    ELSE
                        BEGIN 
                        SELECT @LikeOrDislikeIndicator = LikeOrDislikeIndicator
                        FROM dbo.[UserBlogPreference]
                        WHERE ( BlogId = @a_BlogId AND UserId = @a_UserId )

                        SELECT @ReturnCode = @@ERROR,
                               @RowCount = @@ROWCOUNT

                            IF @ReturnCode <> 0
                               BEGIN 
                                SELECT @Message = 'Critical Error - procedure GetBlogPublishedByBlogId during the 2nd select.'
                                RAISERROR (@Message, 16, 1)
                               END  

                            IF ( @RowCount = 0 )
                                BEGIN
                                    SELECT @LikeDisabled = 0 
                                                           ,@DisLikeDisabled = 0                                
                                END
                            ELSE
                                BEGIN
                                IF @LikeOrDislikeIndicator = 'L'
                                   BEGIN
                                    SELECT @LikeDisabled = 1 
                                                               ,@DisLikeDisabled = 0 
                                   END
                                ELSE
                                   BEGIN
                                      SELECT @LikeDisabled = 0 
                                                             ,@DisLikeDisabled = 1 
                                   END
                                END
                                
                            -- +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++      
                            -- Return data. 
                            --+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                                         SELECT 1 as Status
                                     ,@Blogid as Blogid
                                     ,@BlogTitle as BlogTitle
                                     ,@BlogContent as BlogContent
                                     ,@LikeCount as LikeCount
                                     ,@DisLikeCount as DisLikeCount
                                     ,@ModifiedDateTime as ModifiedDateTime
                                                             ,@CreatedDateTime as CreatedDateTime
                                     ,@LikeDisabled as LikeDisabled
                                                     ,@DisLikeDisabled as DisLikeDisabled
                        END 
               END
           ELSE
               BEGIN

                  RAISERROR (@ApiMessageOut, 16, 1 )
              END
      END
    
   RETURN 0

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    ---- code not shown.       
END CATCH
END
```

---

Here's the UserBlogPreference table that has the indicator used to determine the setting of the LikeDisabled and DisLikeDisabled. It is set as an 'L'.:

[image]

Here is the model class:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace GbngWebApi2.Models
{
    public class BlogPublishedByBlogId
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }        
        public string BlogTitle { get; set; }
        public string BlogContent { get; set; }
        public int LikeCount { get; set; }
        public int DisLikeCount { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
        public bool LikeDisabled { get; set; }
        public bool DisLikeDisabled { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the call to the stored procedure and it is the screen shots above:

```
public BlogPublishedByBlogIdResults GetBlogPublishedByBlogId(string userName, string ipAddress, int blogId, int userId)
{
    BlogPublishedByBlogIdResults blogPublishedByBlogIdResults = new BlogPublishedByBlogIdResults();

    SqlDataReader getblogPublishedByBlogIdReader = null;

    try
    {
        dbFunc.OpenDB();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetBlogPublishedByBlogId", dbFunc.objConn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a_UserName", userName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a_IpAddress", ipAddress);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a_BlogId", blogId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a_UserId", userId);

        getblogPublishedByBlogIdReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        // There will be only 1 entry.
        while (getblogPublishedByBlogIdReader.Read())
        {
            BlogPublishedByBlogId blogPublishedByBlogId = new BlogPublishedByBlogId();

            blogPublishedByBlogIdResults.Status = Convert.ToInt32(getblogPublishedByBlogIdReader["Status"]);
            blogPublishedByBlogId.BlogId = Convert.ToInt32(getblogPublishedByBlogIdReader["BlogId"]);
            blogPublishedByBlogId.BlogTitle = getblogPublishedByBlogIdReader["BlogTitle"].ToString();
            blogPublishedByBlogId.BlogContent = getblogPublishedByBlogIdReader["BlogContent"].ToString();
            blogPublishedByBlogId.LikeCount = Convert.ToInt32(getblogPublishedByBlogIdReader["LikeCount"]);
            blogPublishedByBlogId.DisLikeCount = Convert.ToInt32(getblogPublishedByBlogIdReader["DisLikeCount"]);
            blogPublishedByBlogId.ModifiedDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(getblogPublishedByBlogIdReader["ModifiedDateTime"]);
            blogPublishedByBlogId.CreatedDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(getblogPublishedByBlogIdReader["CreatedDateTime"]);

            // Test code to see what the value is before trying to convert to boolean below.
            int likeDisabled = Convert.ToInt32(getblogPublishedByBlogIdReader["LikeDisabled"]);
            int DislikeDisabled = Convert.ToInt32(getblogPublishedByBlogIdReader["DisLikeDisabled"]);

            blogPublishedByBlogId.LikeDisabled = Convert.ToBoolean(getblogPublishedByBlogIdReader["LikeDisabled"]);
            blogPublishedByBlogId.DisLikeDisabled = Convert.ToBoolean(getblogPublishedByBlogIdReader["DisLikeDisabled"]);

            blogPublishedByBlogIdResults.BlogPublishedByBlogId = blogPublishedByBlogId;
        }

        return blogPublishedByBlogIdResults;
    }
    catch (SqlException sqlex)
    {                
        throw sqlex;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        if (getblogPublishedByBlogIdReader != null)
        {
            getblogPublishedByBlogIdReader.Close();
        }

        dbFunc.CloseDB();
    }
}
```

---

Screen shot using Steve's code (same result - the integer 1 in the LikeDisabled returned from the stored procedure is still being converted to a value of 0):

[image]

---

Screen shot using Steve's code (same result - the integer 1 in the LikeDisabled returned from the stored procedure is still being converted to a value of 0). Also the stored procedure run in SSMS with debugging selects.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: OK..informative but nothing to do with my problem.

Comment: @user3020047 you should pay attention to what one of the lead devs of SO says. This is a bug. There are other bugs in all this code, like *not* using `using`, swallowing exceptions with `catch{}` or cloning exceptions with `throw sqlex` instead of `throw;`. It's hard to read all this code and definitely *impossible* to reproduce the problem. The screenshots are unreadable

Comment: @user3020047 post a *minimal* example that reproduces the problem. You shouldn't need more than a few lines in the stored procedure to return a few hard-coded values and a few lines in the reader to return the record and reproduce the problem. This will allow others to read the code, copy it, compile it and debug it

Comment: Why use an integer instead of a bit as the data type of the boolean field(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDIT 2] Please try this revised method (with added variable to capture the SqlTypes):

```
public BlogPublishedByBlogIdResults GetBlogPublishedByBlogId(string userName, string ipAddress, int blogId, int userId)
    {
        BlogPublishedByBlogIdResults blogPublishedByBlogIdResults = new BlogPublishedByBlogIdResults();

        try
        {
            dbFunc.OpenDB();

            using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetBlogPublishedByBlogId", dbFunc.objConn))
            {
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                var uName = sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@a_UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255);
                uName.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                uName.Value = userName;
                var ipAddr = sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@a_IpAddress", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255);
                ipAddr.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                ipAddr.Value = ipAddress;
                var blId = sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@a_BlogId", SqlDbType.Int);
                blId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                blId.Value = userName;
                var uId = sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@a_UserName", SqlDbType.Int);
                uId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                uId.Value = userName;

                using (var sqlDataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sqlDataReader.Read())
                    {
                        // Get the SQL Server raw values by column offset
                        var sqlStatus = sqlDataReader.GetSqlInt32(0).Value;
                        var sqlBlogId = sqlDataReader.GetSqlInt32(1).Value;
                        var sqlBlogTitle = sqlDataReader.GetSqlString(2).Value;
                        var sqlBlogContent = sqlDataReader.GetSqlString(3).Value;
                        var sqlLikeCount = sqlDataReader.GetSqlInt32(4).Value;
                        var sqlDisLikeCount = sqlDataReader.GetSqlInt32(5).Value;
                        var sqlModDate = sqlDataReader.GetSqlDateTime(6).Value;
                        var sqlCreateDate = sqlDataReader.GetSqlDateTime(7).Value;
                        var sqlLikeDisabled = sqlDataReader.GetSqlInt32(8).Value;
                        var sqlDisLikeDisabled = sqlDataReader.GetSqlInt32(9).Value;

                        BlogPublishedByBlogId blogPublishedByBlogId = new BlogPublishedByBlogId();
                        blogPublishedByBlogIdResults.Status = Convert.ToInt32(sqlDataReader["Status"]);
                        blogPublishedByBlogId.BlogId = Convert.ToInt32(sqlDataReader["BlogId"]);
                        blogPublishedByBlogId.BlogTitle = sqlDataReader["BlogTitle"].ToString();
                        blogPublishedByBlogId.BlogContent = sqlDataReader["BlogContent"].ToString();
                        blogPublishedByBlogId.LikeCount = Convert.ToInt32(sqlDataReader["LikeCount"]);
                        blogPublishedByBlogId.DisLikeCount = Convert.ToInt32(sqlDataReader["DisLikeCount"]);
                        blogPublishedByBlogId.ModifiedDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(sqlDataReader["ModifiedDateTime"]);
                        blogPublishedByBlogId.CreatedDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(sqlDataReader["CreatedDateTime"]);

                        // Test code to see what the value is before trying to convert to boolean below.
                        int likeDisabled = Convert.ToInt32(sqlDataReader["LikeDisabled"]);
                        int DislikeDisabled = Convert.ToInt32(sqlDataReader["DisLikeDisabled"]);

                        blogPublishedByBlogId.LikeDisabled = Convert.ToBoolean(sqlDataReader["LikeDisabled"]);
                        blogPublishedByBlogId.DisLikeDisabled = Convert.ToBoolean(sqlDataReader["DisLikeDisabled"]);

                        blogPublishedByBlogIdResults.BlogPublishedByBlogId = blogPublishedByBlogId;
                    }
                    return blogPublishedByBlogIdResults;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlex)
        {
            throw sqlex;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            if (getblogPublishedByBlogIdReader != null)
            {
                getblogPublishedByBlogIdReader.Close();
            }

            dbFunc.CloseDB();
        }
    }
```

You could try using the system data types library.  SqlInt32 does not convert to CLR boolean.  It's vastly easier to return the integer as a SqlBoolean.  This is its actual purpose because there's no such thing as a "SQL Boolean" there's BIT.  Anyway, the type library is a whole topic.  Conversions from Sql types to CLR types requires testing to make sure it's not null.

```
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
```

Then explicitly convert from the DataReader.  If you know the value is never null you could use

```
var yourVar = (bool)sqlDataReader.GetSqlBoolean(0);
```

If it could be null  you could use

```
var x = sqlDataReader.GetSqlBoolean(0).IsNull ? false : (bool)sqlDataReader.GetSqlBoolean(0);
```

Comment: Ignoring the boolean conversion for now, I try to do a simple convert of the returned value of 1 to an integer and it sets it to a value of 0. Using: int likeDisabled = Convert.ToInt32(getblogPublishedByBlogIdReader["LikeDisabled"]);

Comment: Yeah I see what's going on.  Your datareader is returning an object of type object.  The object is being converted into a CLR Int32 as 0.  The SqlTypes library is the proper way to do this.  If you just want it to work most of the time you could try adding .ToString() to the end of getblogPublishedByBlogIdReader["LikeDisabled"]

Comment: Steve, I tried adding the ToStrin(). Same result. Weird part is the LikeCount and DisLikeCount which are both integers also are converted just fine.

Comment: That's ToString()

Comment: LikeCount and DisLikeCount are either 1 or 0.  BlogId is 40.  Could you change the SQL so that a 1 or 0 is returned (since it's target Property is boolean)?

Comment: LikeCount and DisLikeCount are integer counters and will be greater than 1 or 0 as time goes by. Their target properties are int. LikeDisabled and DisLikeDisabled are either 1 or 0 and their target properties are bool. LikeDisabled is coming back from stored proc as 1 and I'm trying to convert is to boolean true. But it is not doing it because the value is 0 and is being converted to false. It is totally not getting it as the value 1.

Comment: I change the stored procedure to return and integer 5 as the LikeDisabled and it shows as 0 when it is being converted to integer in that test code I have. It is totally not getting it as the value 5.How weird! Completely baffles me as its a simple thing here..

Comment: That's the answer tho, right?  If it's other than a 1 or 0 (a legit 0) it's being returned as 0.  The SqlTypes library and the what marc_s wrote above about using .Add instead of .AddWithValue are good recommendations.  Points-worthy :)

Comment: No, its not the answer. The stored proc returns LikeDisabled and DisLikeDisabled as either 1 or 0 which I want to convert to their target properties as bool. But LikeDisabled is coming back from stored proc as 1 but the ADO data reader thinks it's a 0 not a 1. It's all depicted in the screen shots above. I do this all the time and never had this problem before.

Comment: int likeDisabled does not get passed into the Convert.ToInt32 method.  For that it references the reader.

Comment: Try this: blogPublishedByBlogId.LikeDisabled = Convert.ToBoolean(likeDisabled);

Comment: int likeDisabled receives the result of the convert function which should be a 1 as that is what is returned from the stored procedure, but the outcome is a 0.  int likeDisabled = Convert.ToInt32(getblogPublishedByBlogIdReader["LikeDisabled"]);

Comment: Maybe the stored procedure isn't returning what it's supposed to because the input parameters are not being specified in a type safe manner.  I updated with an attempt to refactor your method to use .Add and Using{} variables which are disposable.

Comment: If you look at the screen shot you will see that it returns the 1 in the LikeDisabled column. And all the other data is as it is supposed to be.

Comment: How was the proc run, from SSMS?  Then you test the same inputs using the C#?  When you assign the parameters to the procedure your code uses cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a_BlogId", blogId);.  It doesn't specify the SQL type of the parameters and that can lead to unpredictable results.  .Add specifies the SQL types of the parameters.

Comment: Steve, I hear you about using that input .Add coding approach but I have at least 20 ADO calls using stored procedures in this app doing it the way this one does with .AddWithValue and they all work fine. So I really don't think that is my issue here.

Comment: I will give it a shot.

Comment: Steve, I changed the code to use .Add  as per your code suggestion depicted above. However, it did not change the result. Same issue. It still converts the int 1 in LikeDisabled returned by the stored procedure to a 0. I included a screenshot.

Comment: We have to establish what output the procedure is returning to C#.  To do this we need to use the SqlTypes library.  That's what I wrote initially.  I updated the method GetBlogPublishedByBlogId again with new variables to get the raw SQL values returned to C#.  This reads from the SqlDataReader by offset and returns the Sql Values.

Comment: I ran your updated method. Still the same results. Also, I ran the stored procedure in SSMS and added some selects for debugging. The stored procedure outputs the correct values. It's on the C# side somehow. See the new screen shots added to reflect these attempts.

Comment: The GetInt32() method is the actual data that's delivered to C#.  From the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getsqlint32?view=sqlclient-dotnet-core-2.0).  It says in the remarks: "No conversions are performed" and I've looked at the base assembly source code and that is the case.  So I'm convinced the proc is returning the value 0 in the offset(8) column.

Comment: If you're convinced it's C# then it could be that there's another implementation of the BlogPublishedByBlogId class in a different namespace and you're referencing that one.  Is that impossible?

Comment: sqlDataReader.GetSqlInt32(8).Value I meant to write

Comment: Steve, I found the bug, I was not passing in a 'user id' to the api. The stored procedure was sending back a 0 for the LikeDisabled as it was supposed to. I however was testing and debugging the stored procedure with a valid 'user id'. Hence, I was believing that data and that bug sent me down this crazy path. All the code was working as it should have. Thanks so much for all your help in looking into this. It did ultimately find the real bug. I will be deleting this post as it really has no value for anyone.

Comment: Glad if i helped!  Cheers.  Btw, I'm the [author](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PBREgTkFeDE&t=720s) of an open source [C# library](https://github.com/The-Cantor-Set/JsonAutoService) the automates building database first API's using stored procedures.  I believe you would find this to be truly useful.  Anyway FWIW, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Logically it should work.
The only possibility is that DisLikeDisabled is 0 in Db.
You can Use alternate for that as well

```
 blogPublishedByBlogId.LikeDisabled =(getblogPublishedByBlogIdReader["LikeDisabled"] == 1) ? True : False;
```

Comment: Its's not the DisLikeDisabled. It's the LikeDisabled and they both are set in the stored procedure that was called. The screenshot shows the result of that call and LikeDisabled is a value of 1. Odd as it should work. It's a simple conversion.

Comment: I added a screen shot of the stored procedure that sets these 2 returned values. The others are from a database table.

Comment: @user3020047 all this code and screenshots are unreadable. Post a *small* example instead, something people can actually read

Comment: FYi..just click on the screen shots and they get larger and more readable.